# Excel: How to count cells, whose date values represent a day between monday and friday?

Tags: worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013, countif

I want to count cells, whose values are dates, under the following condition: The date value entered must be a day between Monday and Friday.

Assume the following data and my try:

```
Column A
--
15.01.2015 (5)
16.01.2015 (6)
17.01.2015 (7)
18.01.2015 (1)
19.01.2015 (2)
```

The function `WEEKDAY` seems to be practical to use. It returns `1` for a Monday through `7` for a Sunday.

Formula: `=COUNTIF( A:A; WEEKDAY(A:A; 1) < 6 )`

For now my formula returns `0`, but `3` is expected.

How can I change it to the right behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think `COUNTIF` will be able to do what you want without the use of a helper column. So, give the following array formula a try.

Enter this formula,

```
=SUM(N(WEEKDAY(A1:A5)>6))
```

the press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> to make it an array formula.

The end resulting formula will look like this.

```
{=SUM(N(WEEKDAY(A1:A5)>6))}
```

*Note: The column reference `A:A` will not work. You have to give the actual range.*

Comment: The reason the `A:A` formula does not work is that the blank cells return `7` which is counted by the formula.  Instead try this: `{=SUM(N(WEEKDAY(A:A,2)<6))}`.  Though I am afraid it only work in Office 2013 and later.  In previous versions, the WEEKDAY formula had different options and does not include for Numbers 1 (Monday) to 7 (Sunday)